# Uniform integrabiliy of submartinales

Tags: probability, martingales, uniform-integrability

Let $\mathcal X=(X_i)_{i\in I}$ be a family of integrable, real valued random variables on $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$. One easily sees that $\mathcal X$ is uniformly integrable *iff* both $\mathcal X^+=((X_i)^+)_{i\in I}$ and $\mathcal X^-=((X_i)^-)_{i\in I}$ are uniformly integrable.

---

### Question :

Suppose $\mathcal S=(S_t)_{t\geq 0}$ is a *sub*martingale. Is $\mathcal S^-$ automatically uniformly integrable ? i.e. is $\mathcal S$ uniformly integrable *iff* $\mathcal S^+$ is uniformly integrable ?

---

**Note :**

1. there is a filtration lurking in the background which I did not mention, and didn't *a priori* impose any assumptions on. Feel free to do so if needed.
2. I am interested both in the discrete and continuous time case, with $\mathcal S$ (right) continuous if needed.
3. The question is inspired by a [recent question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2593182/uniform-integrability-of-stopped-submartinales) about the uniform integrability of the family of stopped processes of a uniformly integrable submartinale. I didn't write down the details, but it seems that, if true, the above may facilitate the application of, say, the [de la Vallée-Poussin criterion for uniform integrability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_integrability#Relevant_theorems).
4. Part of the motivation for this question stems from the observation that a submartinale $\mathcal S$ is bounded in $L^1$ *iff* $\mathcal S^+$ is bounded in $L^1$. Of course being bounded in $L^1$ is necessary for being uniformly integrable.

Comment: This question has been answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2594172/36150